# Using LWUIT how to change the style of the text in a FormItem and the background color of a PopupChoiceGroup?

Tags: java-me, styles, lwuit, nokia

I've begun to use LWUIT for Nokia Asha SDK 1.2 and so far I've gotten the hang of how styles work, but for elements such as **FormItem** I haven't found a way to do what I want.

Normally you would change the style of a **Component** in code like this:

`component.getStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);`

But when dealing with a two-line **FormItem**, how can I make the font in both lines of the **FormItem** to be a specific *size*, *weight*, **color**, etc.?

If I declare a two-line **FormItem** like this:

`FormItem item = new FormItem("First Name", "Enter first name", false);`

A similar problem happens with a **PopupChoiceGroup**, where I try to change the background color of it, by default the background color of this component is ligh gray, but I want to make it completely white. This is how I instantiate the **PopupChoiceGroup**:

```
    titleChoice = new PopupChoiceGroup(Main.localize("TITLE"), null, titleChoices, PopupChoiceGroup.SINGLE);
```

And I've tried the following lines to change the background color, with no success so far:

```
    titleChoice.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);

    titleChoice.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);

    titleChoice.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

    titleChoice.getStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);
```

How can I change the style of these components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any way to edit the fonts on the `FormItem` [class](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/LWUIT/_zip/GUID-2C0A76F0-B646-489D-9553-9FD58B34571F/com/nokia/lwuit/components/FormItem.html) directly. It looks like you would have to create a custom component based on the `FormItem` [class](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/LWUIT/_zip/GUID-2C0A76F0-B646-489D-9553-9FD58B34571F/com/nokia/lwuit/components/FormItem.html), create a custom font object and draw (paint) the component using the custom font. Rather than posting the (rather long) code snippet I am including a link to [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_freely_resizable_font_in_in_Java_ME) page with an example that describes the process.

Related Nokia forum post [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/198048-Font-Size-Enlargement).

The same goes for the PopupChoiceGroup [class](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/LWUIT/_zip/GUID-2C0A76F0-B646-489D-9553-9FD58B34571F/com/nokia/lwuit/components/PopupChoiceGroup.html). The process to alter the background is similar.

Comment: does this apply to other Components such as GroupHeader? That one is giving me trouble too with its background color. Anyway thanks for replying and for the links, good thing I can do this using the pain method.

Comment: Yes, there isn't any direct method exposed to change the background color on GroupHeader as well: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/LWUIT/_zip/GUID-2C0A76F0-B646-489D-9553-9FD58B34571F/com/nokia/lwuit/components/GroupHeader.html

Comment: One might think this can be done by setting the properties with the reference to the style object of the component, too bad for this, even if I use the LWUIT Resource Editor I couldn't alter the background color.